# Media Query not overriding webkit calc

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

I have a calc definition:

```
#navigation-panel {
     a, i.navEmptyBlock {    
        // ...
        width: -webkit-calc(12% - 2px);
        width: -moz-calc(12% - 2px);
        width: -o-calc(12% - 2px);
        width: -ms-calc(12% - 2px);
        width: calc(12% - 2px);

        @media (max-width: 640px) {      
          width: -webkit-calc(20% - 2px);
          width: -moz-calc(20% - 2px);
          width: -o-calc(20% - 2px);
          width: -ms-calc(20% - 2px);
          width: calc(20% - 2px);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

When resized at 640px it should apply the new calc, but it doesn't.

I've inspected with Google Developer Tools and the new calc **DOES** apply but it's not overriding the old one for any weird reason.

Developer Tools shows old one crossed out but it's **still applying it!**. If I disable the crossed one it works.

**Tried in firefox and it works.**

It seems chrome doesn't override `-webkit-calc` calls?

Generated Code from COMPASS:

```
#navigation-panel a, #navigation-panel i.navEmptyBlock {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #080808;
  text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: relative;
  width: -webkit-calc(12% - 2px);
  width: -moz-calc(12% - 2px);
  width: -o-calc(12% - 2px);
  width: -ms-calc(12% - 2px);
  width: calc(12% - 2px);
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #3284b6;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 6px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  /* Windows */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-transition: background 80ms;
  font-weight: 800;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); }
  @media (max-width: 640px) {
    #navigation-panel a, #navigation-panel i.navEmptyBlock {
      width: -webkit-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -moz-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -o-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -ms-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: calc(20% - 2px); } }
```

**EDIT:** The plain width does override the first calc, but second cald overrides the new plain width but does not apply!

Comment: Is this using LESS or Sass?

Comment: @cimmanon Its a Compass app.

Comment: Could you post the relevant generated CSS instead of the makros?

Comment: Using what I assume to be the generated CSS in a fiddle, it looks like it should work (added a bit of extra styling so you can see when the media query is applied):  http://jsfiddle.net/nPKVp/1/.  You have an issue with the generated CSS somewhere.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/nPKVp/2/.  The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the webkit's prefixes in a repeated selector works somehow.

```
a, i.navEmptyBlock {    
        @media (max-width: 640px) {
          // fallback
          width: 18%;
          width: -webkit-calc(20% - 2px);         
        }
        @media (max-width: 565px) {
          // fallback
          width: 19%;
          width: -webkit-calc(20% - 2px);          
        }    
        @media (max-width: 355px) {
          // fallback
          width: 15.5%;
          width: -webkit-calc(20% - 2px);       
        }
      }
    a, i.navEmptyBlock {    
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $nav-panel-font-color;
        text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);   
        position: rela
```

tive;
        width: 12%;

```
    width: -moz-calc(12% - 0.18em);
    width: -o-calc(12% - 0.18em);
    width: -ms-calc(12% - 0.18em);
    width: calc(12% - 0.18em);

    @media (max-width: 640px) {
      // fallback
      width: 19%;          
      width: -moz-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -o-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -ms-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: calc(20% - 2px);
    }
    @media (max-width: 565px) {            
      width: -moz-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -o-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -ms-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: calc(20% - 2px);
    }    
    @media (max-width: 355px) {           
      width: -moz-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -o-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: -ms-calc(20% - 2px);
      width: calc(20% - 2px);
    }
```